# Select Sum and multiple columns in 1 select statement

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, select, sum

Is there a way to select the sum of a column and other columns at the same time in SQL?

Example:

```
SELECT sum(a) as car,b,c FROM toys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add GROUP BY

```
SELECT sum(a) as car,b,c FROM toys 
GROUP BY b, c
```

Comment: grouping works, but what happens if i use a Where clause at the end?

Comment: you don't add where clause at the end, you add where clause where it is suppose to be added

Comment: where clause goes before group by and nothing bad will happen resultset will be filtered and sum will be evaluated on it.

Comment: one thing you should care of is: in select part alowed only aggregation functions and fields presented in group by

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
select sum(a) over(), b, c from toy;
```

or, if it's required:

```
select sum(a) over(partition by b), b, c from toy;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b,
 c,
 (SELECT sum(a) FROM toys) as 'car'
FROM toys
```

Comment: What happens if my columns b and c are retrieved based on a where condition?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give much context, I assume you mean one of the following :

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(a) FROM Toys) as 'car', b, c FROM Toys;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(a) as Car, b, c FROM Toys GROUP BY b, c;
```

Comment: What do you mean what you do? YOu have to stick it between the Toys and the GROUP, like : SELECT ... FROM Toys WHERE .... GROUP BY b, c;

Comment: I think @tdjfdjdj was talking about the first example..
You'll end up in using two where clauses in it..!!